# How to intercept ASP.NET markup parsing?

Tags: asp.net, parsing, localization

I'm dealing with localization of an ASP.NET web application.

The implicit localization mechanism suits best my requirements. However, in order to use it I need the `meta:resourcekey="KeyInTheResourceFile"`

I'm wondering if there is a way to intercept the parsing of markup - .aspx file for instanse - for every single child control and add this meta thing just before ASP.NET parser convert it to an actual control.  This way, I believe ASP.NET itself will enforce implicit localization without the need to add this `meta:resourcekey=...` on each and every control present in the web site. The resource key would be the control ID or be based on some other logic so I will need to author only the resource files themselves.

I found about TemplateControl.ParseControl method but it seem to be non-virtual and I cannot override it.

**So the main question is am I on the right track at all?**
**Should I mess with the parsing or there is a better way to achieve implicit localization?**

Comment: What sort of "implicit localization" do you need?

Comment: Hi, John! In ASP.NET there are two types of localization: Implicit and Explicit. Take a look at this walkthrough [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f(v=vs.80).aspx). I want to use "implicit localization", so all the properties will be "described" in the resource file itself. But I don't want manually edit each and evry tag in my website to put `meta:ResourceKey="ControlId"`. Instead I would like to, somehow intercept the parser at a point just before it parses the string declaration of the control in the aspx file and add this parser specific attribute programatically.